# Ajax With Show View for Player

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

So I'm developing a music website and I'm using ajax for a player that's fixed at the bottom.

Previously I've been using the show route for my player.

Here is the erb link:

```
<%= link_to(post, locals: { post: @post }  ,:remote => true) do %>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="<%= post.image %>"/></img>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And my controller show method looks like this:

```
def show
 respond_to do |format|
   format.js
   format.html
  end
end
```

My question is, how would I go about making a route that is basically the same thing as my show route (or passes the same information)?

Maybe something like /post/:id/play or something?

Or should I just stick to using the show route.

OR, is there a way to specify what format.js is used in the link_to section. Can I have a file called palyer.js and specify that in the link_to?

Thank you!

My show.js file

```
$('#player').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'layouts/player', locals: { post: @post }) %>");
```

Comment: You can specify what partial is used when you call format.js by passing a block and calling `render 'player'`. So `format.js { render 'player' }`

Comment: Hi CWitty, justed updated the post. I added the code I have in my show.js file.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use the show route? Does it not make sense from the url when used in this context? If you do wish to create a route for a non restful action you can do so by passing a block to the resources method in the routes file and then do `get play, on: :member` in the block. I'm on my phone now but I believe that is the syntax. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

Comment: Oh I see. You're link really helped me. I've made a route  
get 'posts/play/:id/', to: 'posts#play' 

it seems to be doing what I want! Thank you

Comment: If you add a `as: :play` to the end of your member route it will generate a path helper.